# Converting string to C style string

Tags: c++, string, cstring

I am trying to convert an int to a cstring. I've decided to read the int into a regular string via stringstream, and then read the string into a char array. The following seems to be working, but I'm wondering if I'm just getting lucky with my compiler. Does the code seem sound? Thanks!

```
int zip = 1234;    

char zipString[30];

stringstream str;

str << zip;

str >> zipString;

cout << zipString;
```

Comment: better move this question to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Any reason you need to have the string as a c-string rather than a `std::string`? The latter is generally a much better option unless you're hamstrung by legacy code.

Comment: I need to deal with each 'integer' in the string independently. It seemed like an array would allow me to pick them off in order the easiest.

Comment: @IniquiTrance: `std::string` can also be indexed like an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a C++ `std::string` from the stream's `str()` function, and an immutable C-style zero-terminated string from the string's `c_str()` function:

```
std::string cpp_string = str.str();
char const * c_string = cpp_string.c_str();
```

You might be tempted to combine these into a single expression, `str.str().c_str()`, but that would be *wrong*; the C++ string will be destroyed before you can do anything with the pointer.

What you are doing will work, as long as you're sure that the buffer is large enough; but using the C++ string removes the danger of overflowing the buffer. In general, it's best to avoid C-style strings unless you need to use an API that requires them (or, in extreme circumstances, as an optimisation to avoid memory allocation). `std::string` is usually safer and easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, would you advise against doing what I did?

Comment: You're right! I thought `stringstream.str()` returned `std::string&`, not `std::string` :)

Comment: @IniquiTrance: In general I'd advise using `std::string` for strings unless there's a compelling reason to use something else.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a specific reason that you need an array of char instead of a standard string, I'd use the latter. Although it's not strictly necessary in this case, I'd also normally use a Boost [`lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) instead of explicitly moving things through a stringstream to do the conversion:

```
std::string zipString = lexical_cast<std::string>(zip);
```

Then, if you really need the result as a c-style string, you can use `zipString.c_str()` to get that (though it's still different in one way -- you can't modify what that returns).

In this specific case it doesn't gain you a lot, but consistent use for conversions on this general order adds up, and if you're going to do that, you might as well use it here too.

Comment: You gain fail fast behavior, which is a lot.  I've never seen an entire organization check stream's fail bits consistently (@IniquiTrance included).

Answer (score 1):

The `std::string`'s `c_str()` member function returns a `const char*` (aka a C-style string).

```
std::string str = "world";
printf("hello, %s", str.c_str());
```